# Is there a way to save custom equalizer settings in Music?

Tags: music

Is it possible to save custom equalizer presets in Music?

I like to get the best audio out of my audio, so how can I audio my audio while I audio?

Comment: too much audio bro

Comment: @Adityaultra there can never be too much audio, homie ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Saving custom equalizer setting**

In noise version 0.3.1 there is an icon in the textfield where the name of the equalizer setting is displayed. With this icon ("arrow down") you can save your custom equalizer.

[image: saving custom equalizer setting]